# What is @Service in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If I use `@Service` on a service class, do I need to make a service class bean in my servlet xml file or do I have to do both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to declare a bean in your context file if you:

1) Annotate the class with:

```
@Component, @Service, @Controller or @Repository
```

2) Include the context:component-scan element in your context file like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i tried that my @controller is working but not @Service('userService')

Comment: Could you be more specific? How are you injecting an instance of your service bean? Have you annotated with @Resource the member of the class on which you want the service bean to be injected?

Comment: Is the reference an interface type?

Comment: i  followed this example  http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jdbc-integration-tutorial.html

Comment: `@Resource
private IService service;`

Comment: i found the problem actually i chose the base package for all controllers but my service was in diff folder , so now i have included that and its working now

Answer (score 5):

Last time I looked (Spring 2.5) [@Service](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) was a marker annotation subclassed from [@Component](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), but with no additional behaviour.  Which means that beans tagged with [@Service](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) become candidates for auto detection if you are using annotation-based configuration via classpath scanning.

As per the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html), the intention is that this annotation might include service layer specific functionality in future Spring releases.  It can also act as an AOP point cut for all of your service layer components.

Comment: i have spring 3. so u mean thats only for AOP and i still need to declare class object in xml file